# Removing creatures from my library in game

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Looking for a way to utilise [Mortal Combat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMortal%20Combat%5d) as a win strategy and was wondering if there are any way to get my creatures into my graveyard without self mill. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Don't you by definition want self-mill? You're trying to move cards from your library to your graveyard, and that's what self-mill is. I guess maybe you're hoping for something that specifically pulls out lots of creatures and leaves the rest alone?

Answer (score 6):

[Iname, Death Aspect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIname%2c%20Death%20Aspect%5d).  Sadly, I can't take credit for this.  [Saffron Olive figured that out](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/against-the-odds-mortal-combat-spirits-modern).